# \psboxfill cannot work with a starred \pspicture

Tags: pstricks

When `\psboxfill` encloses `\pspicture*`, I got a strange result as follows.

[image]

```
\documentclass[cmyk]{minimal}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-fill}

\psboxfill{%
\psset{unit=1pt}
\begin{pspicture*}(1,1)
\psline(-1,-1)(2,2)
\psline(-1,2)(2,-1)
\end{pspicture*}%
}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-2,-2)(2,2)
\pscircle[
    fillstyle=solid,
    opacity=0.25,
    fillcolor=gray,
    fillsep=0.4,
    addfillstyle=boxfill]
    (0,0){2}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

It means the `\psboxfill` cannot work with clipped `\pspicture` that are sometimes needed in our tasks. Is it a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clipping inside a clipping region is difficult. Use this definition:

```
\psboxfill{%
  \psset{unit=2pt,linewidth=0.4pt}% to make the x-like filling objects visible
  \AltClipMode
  \begin{pspicture*}(1,1)
  \psline(-1,-1)(2,2)
  \psline(-1,2)(2,-1)
  \end{pspicture*}%
}
```

Comment: +1 I need to adjust the `linewidth`.